# Create a new array based of of day index and the day

Tags: php

I'm having trouble trying to create a new array based on day_index and checking to see if that day exists or not in an array of objects.

`$working_hours_arr` contains the *working* days; I'd like to create a new array based on this where if the day_index doesn't exist in this array, to add that day and the state working to false (and the day_index), if it does exist, add `working` with `true` and the day index.

How can I do this?

The current output is that none matches.

```
$working_hours_arr = '[{"day_index":"2","start_time":"10:00:00","end_time":"19:00:00","break":[]},{"day_index":"3","start_time":"11:00:00","end_time":"20:00:00","break":[]},{"day_index":"4","start_time":"10:00:00","end_time":"19:00:00","break":[]},{"day_index":"5","start_time":"11:00:00","end_time":"20:00:00","break":[]}]';

$days = [
    'Sunday' => 1,
    'Monday' => 2,
    'Tuesday' => 3,
    'Wednesday' => 4,
    'Thursday' => 5,
    'Friday' => 6,
    'Saturday' => 7,
];

$schedule = [];
foreach ($days as $day => $index) {
    foreach(json_decode($working_hours_arr) as $obj) {
        $dayIndex = (int)$obj->day_index;
        if ($index == $dayIndex) {
            $schedule[$day] = ['day_index' => $index];
            $schedule[$day] = ['working' => true]; 
        } else {
            $schedule[$day] = ['day_index' => $index];
            $schedule[$day] = ['working' => false]; 
        }
    }
}

var_dump($schedule);
```

Comment: Don't you need a ,1 in the json_decode?  `json_decode($working_hours_arr)`  You should have included  a dump of $working_hours_arr and Schedule.   And why would you.. no your code is giving me anxiety.

Comment: Haha not that great in PHP, would love your suggestions to improve this code! @Misunderstood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break out of the loop if your `IF` condition is satisfied. Add a `break;` in the `IF` condition. Your `BOOL` key of `['working' => true]` will work now.

```
if ($index == $dayIndex) {
    $schedule[$day] = ['day_index' => $index];
    $schedule[$day] = ['working' => true]; 
    break;
} else {
    $schedule[$day] = ['day_index' => $index];
    $schedule[$day] = ['working' => false]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your JSON is not being decoded.
I'm not sure what is wrong, but json_decode does not report an error but the resulting array is NULL.
The following code outputs NULL
I would have expected something from json_last_error() with a NULL result.

```
   $working_hours_arr = '[{"day_index":"2","start_time":"10:00:00","end_time":"19:00:00","break":[]},{"day_index":"3","start_time":"11:00:00","end_time":"20:00:00","break":[]},{"day_index":"4","start_time":"10:00:00","end_time":"19:00:00","break":[]},{"day_index":"5","start_time":"11:00:00","end_time":"20:00:00","break":[]}]';
   $hours = json_decode($working_hours_arr,1);
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo '';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }   
    var_export($hours);
```